# OWL слайдер листает в пустоту

Tags: html, owl-carousel

Доброй ночи, OWL слайдер почему-то не отображает второй слайд, листает в пустоту... Как решить эту проблему?

Первый слайд:

[image: Первый слайд]

Второй слайд не отображается (Пустота):

[image: Второй слайд]

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img alt="" class="slide-circle" src="img/slide-circle.png">
                <img alt="" class="slide-cloud" src="img/slide-rain-cloud.png">
                <img alt="" class="slide-sun" src="img/slide-sun.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">

        <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1060px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0.25s; width: 6840px;"><div class="owl-item " style="width: 1140px;"></div><div class="owl-item " style="width: 1140px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                        <div class="slider-img">
                            <img alt="" class="slide-girl sppb-wow zoomIn sppb-animated" src="img/44.png" data-sppb-wow-duration="600ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 600ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                        <h3>ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЕ SMART BABY WATCH<br>ДЕТСКИЕ ЧАСЫ С GPS ТРЕКЕРОМ </h3>
                        <h6>Безопасность Вашего ребенка всегда под контролем</h6>
                         <a href="https://smartbabywatch-market.ru/#callback" class="popap button" data-form="Бесплатная консультация" data-text="Бесплатная консультация">Бесплатная консультация</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item" style="width: 1170px;">

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                            <div class="slider-img">
                                <img alt="" class="slide-girl sppb-wow zoomIn sppb-animated" src="img/nomer44.png" data-sppb-wow-duration="600ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 600ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                            <h3>ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЕ SMART BABY WATCH<br>ДЕТСКИЕ ЧАСЫ С GPS ТРЕКЕРОМ </h3>
                            <h6>Безопасность Вашего ребенка всегда под контролем</h6>
                             <a href="https://smartbabywatch-market.ru/#callback" class="popap button" data-form="Бесплатная консультация" data-text="Бесплатная консультация">Бесплатная консультация</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item " style="width: 1170px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                        <div class="slider-img">

                            <img alt="" class="slide-girl sppb-wow zoomIn sppb-animated" src="img/nomer44.png" data-sppb-wow-duration="600ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 600ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                        <h3>ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЕ SMART BABY WATCH<br>ДЕТСКИЕ ЧАСЫ С GPS ТРЕКЕРОМ </h3>
                        <h6>Безопасность Вашего ребенка всегда под контролем</h6>
                          <a href="https://smartbabywatch-market.ru/#callback" class="popap button" data-form="Бесплатная консультация" data-text="Бесплатная консультация">Заявка на GPS-часы</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-nav disabled"><div class="owl-prev">prev</div><div class="owl-next">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots"><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил переписав.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img alt="" class="slide-circle" src="img/slide-circle.png">
                <img alt="" class="slide-cloud" src="img/slide-rain-cloud.png">
                <img alt="" class="slide-sun" src="img/slide-sun.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">

            <div class="owl-item " style="width: 1170px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                        <div class="slider-img">

                            <img alt="" class="slide-girl sppb-wow zoomIn sppb-animated" src="img/nomer44.png" data-sppb-wow-duration="600ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 600ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                        <h3>ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЕ SMART BABY WATCH<br>ДЕТСКИЕ ЧАСЫ С GPS ТРЕКЕРОМ </h3>
                        <h6>Безопасность Вашего ребенка всегда под контролем</h6>
                          <a href="#callback" class="popap button" data-form="Бесплатная консультация" data-text="Бесплатная консультация">Заявка на GPS-часы</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div>
            <div class="owl-item " style="width: 1170px;"><div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                        <div class="slider-img">

                            <img alt="" class="slide-girl sppb-wow zoomIn sppb-animated" src="img/44.png" data-sppb-wow-duration="600ms" data-sppb-wow-delay="300ms" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 600ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomIn;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                        <h3>КАКОЙ-ТО<br>ЗАГОЛОВОК НА СЛАЙДЕРЕ </h3>
                        <h6>Какой-то текст на слайдере</h6>
                          <a href="#callback" class="popap button" data-form="Бесплатная консультация" data-text="Бесплатная консультация">Текст на кнопке</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-nav disabled"><div class="owl-prev">prev</div><div class="owl-next">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots"><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```